How to open an embedded tagged google map in a new tab full-screen style?
I often come across web sites that show their business locations on an embedded tagged google map such as this one:
https://ibis.accor.com/de/ibis-budget.html
Please scroll down to find the map - it does not seem to be easy to find!
Unfortunately the websites show the map only in a limited area of my computer screen, like the one linked above.
Instead I would like to see that map in full-screen mode, for instance in a separate tab.
Zooming into the webpage while zooming out of the map using the "-"-key does is often limited to a certain extent.
Using Firefox and using the "examine" feature did not help me finding some web code that is responsible for showing the map. Using "CTRL U" to look at the source code did not help me (a web dummy) further.
That is why I want to know:
How to open an embedded tagged google map in a new tab full-screen style?

Please edit] the question and link to page showing a map.

DavidPostill, scroll down to find the map. If you provide me with a link that will only show the map instead of that lengthy web page, I'd be happy. :)
